# how to multiply two toIntOrNull() (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

`val hasil = binding.jumlah.text.toString().toIntOrNull() * binding.harga.text.toString().toIntOrNull()`

I'm trying to make a simple application with Kotlin in Android Studio. I tried multiplying two toIntOrNull(), but I got 2 errors

1. Operator call corresponds to a dot-qualified call 'binding.jumlah.text.toString().toIntOrNull().times(binding.harga.text.toString().toIntOrNull())' which is not allowed on a nullable receiver 'binding.jumlah.text.toString().toIntOrNull()'.
2. Type mismatch: inferred type is Int? but Int was expected

Initially I used

`val hasil = binding.sum.text.toString().toInt() * binding.price.text.toString().toInt()`

with this the multiplication can be done, but when I don't enter the input to editText the app crashes.

so how do i multiply two toIntOrNull()?

Comment: What do you expect as the result when either operand is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
fun Int?.orDefault(): Int {
return this ?: 0
}
```

Use

```
val hasil = binding.jumlah.text.toString().toIntOrNull().orDefault() * 
binding.harga.text.toString().toIntOrNull().orDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

Code which you initially used is perfect `val hasil = binding.sum.text.toString().toInt() * binding.price.text.toString().toInt()` but before this code execute , you should put some validation that will check that inputs are empty or not and if inputs are provided by user then those are numbers or not so your app will not crash

```
val input = binding.jumlah.text.toString().trim()

if(input.isEmptyOrNull()){
    showMessage("Please enter number")
}else if(input.isDigitsOnly().not()){
   showMessage("Please enter number")
}else{
   val hasil = binding.sum.text.toString().toInt() *   binding.price.text.toString().toInt()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using adding this function

```
fun String.toIntOrZero() = toIntOrNull() ?: 0
```

And then use it like that

```
val hasil = binding.jumlah.text.toString().toIntOrZero() * binding.harga.text.toString().toIntOrZero()
```